# Flutter Mixed List - How to push every 6 items to grid style with two columns from mixed list?

Tags: flutter

Hi there please help me how to push item from list to grid, i have implement this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/mixed-list , what i want is how to push every 6 MessageItem to grid with two columns. thanks.

here my sample code:

```
 ListView.builder(
        controller: _controller,
        itemCount: widget.ditems.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = widget.ditems[index];
          if (item is HeadingItem) {
          return TabHomeHeaderUi();
          } else if (item is HeadlineItem) {
            return TabHomeHeadline();
          } else if (item is PopularItem) {
            return TabHomePopular();
          } else if (item is MessageItem) {

            return
            //here return 6 item
            ListTile(
        title: Text(item.sender),
        subtitle: Text(item.body),
      );


          }
        },
      ),
```

Comment: your use case is not clear. are you trying to build a simple gridview with two columns? Then use this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html

Comment: thanks for ur feedback, i had implement flutter mixed list, success and the result same like this url https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/mixed-list. please check u will find the final result as i cant upload image here, may problem is from that list ( every 6 items) I want style with two columns not one column like that sample. thanks in advanced.

Comment: so that means, If you have a total of 18 items, then the items (from 1 to 6) will go to the left column, then the next 6 items (from 7 to 12) will go to the right column, and then the next 6 items (from 13 to 18) will go the left column below all the above items. Am i right?

Comment: yes can be like that, in may case like flutter example,  i % 6 == 0
          ? HeadingItem("Heading $i")
          : MessageItem("Sender $i", "Message body $i"),     //this MessageItem return 6 item.  so this return i want style with two columns thats mean 3 on the left column and other 3 on the right column. thanks.

Comment: Use a gridview and return 6 items wrapped in a column widget